# Can I search my up-vote/favorite history?

Tags: support, search

I tried to install Python on yet another computer, and I faced the same problems I faced before, which I have searched on Stack Overflow and located the correct solutions.

I had two choices:

1. Search again (very painful)
2. Browse through my upvote records page by page

I am sure some people would hope they didn't upvote that many because of 2.

Comment: *"Search again (very painful)"* Why is this painful? Because Stack Overflow's built-in search is so terrible? Perhaps using Google (`site:stackoverflow.com`) would be helpful. Searching should *not* be painful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't search the questions you've upvoted.

But if you think a question will help you in future, you can **favourite** it by clicking the **star icon**.

Then you can search it by

```
infavorites:mine keywords [tags]
```